# Changing the value of a cell in excel based on results in a range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to automatize the result of a cell based on the color or data from a range.
Explanation: It will be a "OK" or "NOT OK" in a cell when there are red cells in a range or when there are some words there. Down is the image about an example of the table I want to work with.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzXmZ.png)

I want to know if it is possible to do it only with formula or have to do it through VBA.

Comment: It sounds like it could be solved with a formula combined with conditional formatting but what have you tried?

Comment: I have the impression that the colour is based on the value of the cells, and now you want to base yourself on the colour in order to do something. Wouldn't it be better to base yourself of the values too?

Comment: @Wayne, I tried to use IF combined with OR and COUNTIF, using the values to modify OK or NOT OK..

Comment: @Dominique, Yep, I moved to that after, because I though maybe colours will be more simple to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the color you will have to use vba, you can check the color of a cell with `Cell.Interior.Color`

On a side note, if you do not want to use vba you could use the condition you use for your conditional formatting (Assigning the color to the cell) in the cell formula instead of using the color.

Comment: I can use the data in the cells to determine if OK or NOT OK, kinda the if the value in this range or the value in this range is not "missing" then it is OK, but seems I'm struggling to manage to get the "if any of the cells in the range is not A" part.
I want to avoid VBA because basically I'm not good in VBA, and maybe it will generate even more questions (I know my weakness)

Comment: If you need all the cells in an area to be "ok" you can use multiple conditions tied by AND with the different cells.
If you need at least one cell in the area to be "ok" you can use OR instead, or any other combination of logic that will suit your needs

Comment: That one sounds more closer to what I want.
Thanks for taking your time answering me, appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, in case this is not enough edit the question with your newfound issues and perhaps an example of your code

Comment: Thank you very much, really :)

Comment: remember to select this as answer if your problem is solved, so the question can be flagged as answered :)

Comment: Sorry, my first question here (totally newbie).
Done.